# How to use JQ to copy a single value from a nested array which has duplicate keys

Tags: arrays, json, filter, nested, jq

I have an array of json objects, each with an array of tags.  Specific tags can appear multiple times in the child array but I only want the first matching tag (key+value) copied up onto the parent object.  I've come up with a filter-set but it gives me multiple outputs if the given tag appears more than once in the child array ... I only want the first one.

**Sample Json Input:**

```
[  
  {  
    "name":"integration1",  
    "accountid":111,  
    "tags":[  
      { "key": "env",  
        "values":["prod"]  
      },  
      { "key": "team",  
        "values":["cougar"]  
      }  
    ]  
  },  
  {  
    "name":"integration2",  
    "accountid":222,  
    "tags":[  
      { "key": "env",  
        "values":["prod"]  
      },  
      { "key": "team",  
        "values":["bear"]  
      }  
    ]  
  },  
  {  
    "name":"integration3",  
    "accountid":333,  
    "tags":[  
      { "key": "env",  
        "values":["test"]  
      },  
      { "key": "team",  
        "values":["lemur"]  
      },  
      { "key": "Env",  
        "values":["qa"]  
      }  
    ]  
  }  
]
```

**Filter-set that I came up with:**

```
jq -r '.[] | .tags[].key |= ascii_downcase | .env = (.tags[] | select(.key == "env").values[0])|[.accountid,.name,.env] | @csv' test.json
```

**Example output with undesirable extra line:**

```
111,"integration1","prod"  
222,"integration2","prod"  
333,"integration3","test"  
333,"integration3","qa"  <<<
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `first(<expression>)` to get only the first matching value. In case there are no matching values at all, you can use `first(<expression>, <default_value>)`.

```
jq -r '.[] | .tags[].key |= ascii_downcase | .env = first((.tags[] | select(.key == "env").values[0]),null)|[.accountid,.name,.env] | @csv' test.json
```

Alternatively, if you are going to want to extract other tags similarly, you might prefer to extract them all into one object like this. I'm using `reverse` to meet your requirement of keeping the first match for any given key, otherwise the last match would win.

```
jq -r '.[] | .tags |= ( map({(.key|ascii_downcase): .values[0]}) | reverse | add ) | [.accountid, .name, .tags.env] | @csv'
```

Comment: jq complained with the default value of None ... but worked like a charm when I changed it to a string value `first(expr,"BLANK")` - Thanks.

Comment: Oops, fixed now. Thanks!